# php custom schedule calendar can not display customer names in the date cell

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

[image]I am trying to build a custom car schedule calendar for car rental company which to show all free days in white on the attachment file and busy days in red color. Till now I succeeded to draw the calendar with correct days and style colors but I want also in the td cell to display the customer names for each reservation. Also if possible to merge reservation cells

This is my working code, but whatever I tried I could not pass customer names in dates array so I could somehow recognize which reservation day is for each customer.

```
$datstart2 = "2017-01-01 00:00:00" ;
$datend2 = "2017-01-31 00:00:00" ;
foreach($cars as $cid){
    $query2 = 'select rr.resnumber, DATE_FORMAT( `datestart` , "%Y-%m-%d" ), DATE_FORMAT( `dateend` , "%Y-%m-%d" ), rr.cl_name, rr.totdays from res_cars rc,res_reservations rr where rr.carid="'.$cid.'" and datestart > now() and (datestart BETWEEN "'.$datstart2.'" AND "'.$datend2.'") group by resnumber order by datestart ASC';
    $result2=mysql_query($query2) or die($query2);
    $num_rows2=mysql_num_rows($result2);

    for($j=0;$j<$num_rows2;$j++){
        $row2=mysql_fetch_row($result2);

        $current = strtotime($row2[1]);
        $last = strtotime($row2[2]);
        //here I generate array that contains all busy days between datestart & dateend for each reservation
        while( $current <= $last ){
            $dates1[] = date('Y-m-d', $current);
            $current = strtotime($step, $current);
        }
    }
   //here I generate a new array with all days without reservation for January for the car
    $dates2 array consists all days in the month

    $emptydays=array_diff($dates2,$dates1);

    foreach($dates as $date){
        //here I draw table cell with different styles if the dy is reserved or not
        if(in_array($date,$emptydays)){
            echo '<td class="emptyday">.</td>';
        } else {
           echo '<td class="busyday">X</td>';
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I wish table cells from type busyday to look like:

```
echo '<td class="busyday">Customer names here</td>';
```

but whatever I tried had no success.
Can you guys help me please and show me the correct way to printout the customer names (cl_name) for each reservation and make it look like:

```
echo '<td class="busyday">Customer names here</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to change your `$date` array to instead of storing only dates, you can store an array for each date/customer_name:

```
$dates = array
  (
  array("date"=>"2016-12-10", "customer_name"=>"Customer 1"),
  array("date"=>"2016-12-15", "customer_name"=>"Customer 2"),
  array("date"=>"2016-12-15", "customer_name"=>"Customer 3"),
  array("date"=>"2016-12-20", "customer_name"=>"Customer 4")
  );
```

then you can access it as:

```
echo $dates[0]["date"].": ".$dates[0]["customer_name"];
```

For example in your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($dates as $date){
    if(in_array($date["date"],$emptydays)){
        echo '<td class="emptyday">'.$date["customer_name"].'</td>';
    } else {
       echo '<td class="busyday">'.$date["customer_name"].'</td>';
    }         
 }
```

One more example, in your while loop you can do something like this:

```
array_push($dates, array("date"=>date('Y-m-d', $current),
                         "customer_name"=>$row2["cl_name"]));

$dates1[] = $dates;     // or array_push($dates1, $date);
```

*You mentioned "cl_name" in your question so I take it as the columns name, if not, replace it by the correct name, please.

Comment: #deCrhristo, thank you for your help, I don't know why but this 
 while( $current <= $last ){
            $dates1[] = date('Y-m-d', $current);
            $current = strtotime($step, $current);
        }
doesnt allow me to add customer_name.. Can you show me example code how to add customer_name to dates array? Thanks

Comment: You're welcome" Updated the answer. Please, take a look.

Comment: DeCristo, sorry mate but I could not make your code working due to various errors it returned..

Comment: @thecore7: update again. See if it works. What errors its returning?